# htaccess to redirect a url by removing a section of the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect old URLs to new URLs, the URLs are much the same, I am just getting rid of an extra directory path.  Just don't know the exact syntax:

```
OLD URL: http://www.domain.com/index.php/hello/world/
NEW URL: http://www.domain.com/hello/world/
```

I need to review the code base, it is not my site, but I imagine there may be pages where the index.php is listed further in, for example /about_us/index.php/fred/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php(.*)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top of all of your existing rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(|.+?/)index\.php(/.*|)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: That worked for me, I only made one alteration, I got rid of the slash in the /$1$2 section. Thanks

Comment: Since this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.